# R super assignment vector

Tags: r

I have a function in which I use the superassingment operator to update a variable in the global environment. This works fine as long as it is a single value e.g.

```
    a <<- 3
```

However I get errors with subsets of data frames and data tables e.g.

```
    a <- c(1,2,3)
    a[3] <<- 4
    Error in a[3] <<- 4 : object 'a' not found
```

Any idea why this is and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: `library("fortunes"); fortune(174)` and http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf Circle 6

Comment: This error is confusing though, anybody know where it comes from ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I think it depends from which point in the searchpath the search for the object begins.

Comment: but `<<-` works fine in current environment, and there is no such thing as `[<<-` so I'm not even sure what is executed, `debugonce("<<-");a[3] <<- 4` shows the function isn't even called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The superassignment operator and other scope-breaking techniques should be avoided if at all possible, in particular because it makes for unclear code and confusing situations like these. But if you really, truly had to assign values to a variable that is out of scope, you could use standard assignment inside `eval`:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)

eval(a[3] <- 4, envir = -1)

a
[1] 1 2 4
```

To generalize this further (if performing the assignment inside a function), you may need to use `<<-` inside `eval` anyway.

While changing variables out of scope is still a bad idea, using `eval` at least makes the operation more explicit, since you have to specify the environment in which the expression is to be evaluated.

All that said, scope-breaking assignments are never *necessary*, per se, and you should perhaps find a way to write your script such that this is not relied on.

Comment: Hmm. Strangely, changing the `eval` statement to use `<<-` solves the issue. Yet another reason why superassignment is confusing.

Comment: A way to fix the issue raised by @IceCreamToucan systematically might go something like `f <- function(object, index, value) {
    elements <- sapply(sys.call()[-1], as.character);
    call_text <- paste0(elements[1], "[", elements[2], "] <- ", elements[3]);
    eval(parse(text = call_text), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}`

Comment: I am not sure why this works, but it does! Thanks for the help! I was indeed looking for an assignment within a function

Comment: "I am not sure why this works, but it does" should be interpreted as a warning, and an incentive to consider writing code in a way that does make sense to you. My answer may be correct, but super assignment in R is still a bad idea.