# How to get an R function to have a global effect on a dataframe?

Tags: r, function, rename

I have been trying to create a function which will permanently change a value in specific cells of my data frame. I insert the data frame name, row index I wish to change, and the new name as a string. However, the function seems to change the value name within the local environment but not global.

The function is as follows:

```
#change name function
name_change <- function(df, row, name) {
  df[row, 1] = name
  return(df[row, 1])
}
```

E.g. if data frame was:

| Name | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | 2 |
| Beth | 4 |

The function name_change(df, 2, 'Jess') would change Beth to Jess.

When inserted as raw code it does permanently change the value. But then does not work when used as a function.

```
df[2, 1] = 'Jess'
```

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your function like this:

```
name_change <- function(df, row, name) {
  df[row, 1] = name
  return(df)
}
```

and then assign the result of the function back to the original df, you will get the change you are looking for:

```
df = name_change(df,2,'Jess')
```

Comment: why? because R passed by value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831261/r-pass-by-value-inside-a-function#29831414 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603184/can-you-pass-by-reference-in-r#2603318

Comment: I would rather say bcs R is a mess and it will take a variable from a global scope and instead of updating it (as it usually does in these cases) it will create a copy of the variable in a current scope. It IS indeed confusing.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the solutions already provided is to use the superassignment operator `<<-`. The ordinary assignment `<-` (or '=' you used) operate in your function's `environment` only. The superassignment reaches beyond your function's [closure](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/scoping-and-closures-in-r) and can thus modify the dataframe residing in the [global environment](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html). Note, though, this is a [quick'n'dirty fix only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780307/r-super-assignment-vector#53780393).

That said, the code would read like this:

```
#change name function
dirty_name_change <- function(df, row, name) {
  df[row, 1] <<- name ## note the double arrow
}
```

Comment: good for mentioning it even though it shouldn't be used in any serious code

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the value of the cell, not the mutated df. R passes by arguments by value so you can imagine the function modifying a copy of df passed in. The solution is to return the mutated df and reassign it.

[Can you pass-by-reference in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603184/can-you-pass-by-reference-in-r#2603318)